# c++ Class Header - "error: expected unqualified-id before ')' token"

Tags: c++

I must be overlooking something simple but I have so much to do in so little time that I might just be overworked. Anyway, here's where I'm getting the error.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>

#ifndef Numbers
#define Numbers

class Numbers{
    public:
  Numbers(){capacity=5; used=0; data = new unsigned long[capacity];}
```

It's simply a constructor for the class Numbers. The private area of the class is as follows.

```
    private:
  unsigned long *data;
  std::size_t used;
  std::size_t capacity;
};
```

Again, it's probably something simple that I just can't see and I'm sure others run into the problem as well.

EDIT: error is as follows

```
numbers.h:9:11: error: expected unqualified-id before ')' token
Numbers(){capacity=5; used=0; data = new unsigned long[capacity];}
        ^
```

Comment: Not in this code. [See it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d283efd66134af8).

Comment: When you write a question about a piece of code not working, it's just a basic, fundamental thing to ensure that the code you show us _exhibits that problem_. Otherwise how can we see the problem?

Comment: Please add the error message intact and the line of code that the error is referencing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Telepathy, duh.

Comment: Well, this is extremely frustrating. I've commented out all other code and I still get the same error. I see no mismatched brackets, braces, or parenthesis nor any missing semicolons.

The error is on the line for the constructor. The code appears exactly how I have it written.

The full error has been added. I apologize for leaving that out.

Comment: A. There is nothing wrong with the code you've posted, as kindly demonstrated by @WhozCraig (+1). B. Please don't ever format your code like that, it hurts all of us.

Comment: @user3897532 The code presented here *as-is* is not the problem, the only thing *left* is the context in which it exists on *your* system, which we *don't have*. We're not mind-readers. Keep looking in the surrounding context. The problem isn't in this code. According to your error text this is on row **9** of the source file. Care to show us the first 6 rows we haven't seen yet?

Comment: @Josh What is wrong with my formatting? I don't particularly like the inline implementation, but it was a requirement. I'm sorry if it's messy, I'm new. I'm sure I'll get better.

Comment: [Testcase](http://sscce.org) [Testcase](http://sscce.org) [Testcase](http://sscce.org) [Testcase](http://sscce.org) [Testcase](http://sscce.org) [Testcase](http://sscce.org) [Testcase](http://sscce.org) [Testcase](http://sscce.org) [Testcase](http://sscce.org) The single most important debugging skill you will ever learn. It's fundamental. You will perform it before asking!

Comment: @user3897532 If you want "inline implementation," use an [***initialization list***](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html), like your professor probably wanted.

Comment: Well a few newlines and some indentation wouldn't have killed you

Comment: @WhozCraig Well thank you for the input. I don't have any semicolons with any macros.

I'm quite sorry if I haven't formatted my question correctly. I'd be happy to change or add anything that would be helpful. I'm using g++ (gcc version 4.8.2) for compilation on a remote UNIX system

Comment: @user3897532 the first six lines of the source file would be good to see. Add it to the top of the already-posted code (which contains lines 7-9 already).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sorry, that's the only one that is all on a single line as it is a bit short.

Comment: @user3897532: Eh? Put it on multiple lines. It's not hard.

Comment: Before you do _anything_ else here, even commenting, read the website I linked you to. At least twice.

Comment: Your `include` fencepost is the same name as your class. you don't think that is a problem? Everywhere in the rest of the translation unit where `Numbers` appears it will be replaced with **nothing**. Use `MYAPP_NUMBERS_H` for your fencepost macro instead.

Comment: @WhozCraig Oh man. I honestly wasn't even looking at those for some reason. I've been working on a lot lately and it's making me make some simple mistakes. Thank you for your input. Hopefully I will ask my questions properly next time.

Comment: Hopefully you will include the entire testcase next time. You said that this was your whole code, and you were lying. >.<

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run through the preprocessor, this:

```
#ifndef Numbers
#define Numbers

class Numbers{
    public:
  Numbers(){capacity=5; used=0; data = new unsigned long[capacity];}
```

becomes  *this* :

```
class {
    public:
  () {capacity=5; used=0; data = new unsigned long[capacity];}
```

Your class name is the same as your include-guard fencepost macro. Since `Numbers` will be replaced with.. *nothing*.. you get no class name, nor constructor name. Don't do that.

Try:

```
#ifndef MYAPP_NUMBERS_H
#define MYAPP_NUMBERS_H

#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

class Numbers
{
public:
    Numbers()
    {
        capacity=5; 
        used=0; 
        data = new unsigned long[capacity];
    }

...etc...
```

Comment: Thank you. Those were explained very poorly and briefly by a previous professor who never bothered to use them but mentioned that we should and left it at that. I'm very happy to have learned something today.